# Parse proprietary returnstring form a Server

Tags: c#, linq

i Need to parse a proprietary string from a tcp Server.
the string i get is the following:

```
!re.tag=3=.id=*1=name=1 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~!re.tag=3=.id=*2=name=3 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~!done.tag=3~
```

So when striping off the !done.tag.... and Splitting the string at the ~ I can break down the (in this case) two objects to

```
!re.tag=3=.id=*1=name=1 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~
!re.tag=3=.id=*2=name=3 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~
```

then im facing the Problem, how to split the properties and their values.

```
!re.tag=3
=.id=*2
=name=3 Hour
=owner=admin
=name-for-users=
=validity=3h
=starts-at=logon
=price=0
=override-shared-users=off
```

Normally i'll do a split on the equals sign, like this:

```
 List<string> arProfiles = profilString.Split('=').ToList();
```

and then i can guess(!) that the value of the "name" property is at Position 5.

Is there a more proper way to parse these kind of strings (these while i'll get the same kind of strings from different functions)

Paul

Comment: Why are you guessing? Don't you have documentation for what this string means and how it is structured?

Comment: I would like make my compliments to the creator of this proprietary format string

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am guessing, while the creator of this Format had changed something in the latest Firmware and then my code didnt work any more (they had added another equals sign, in the past the value of Name was on Position 4)

Comment: @wintermute i guess you are ironic :)

Comment: It looks like after that split on `=`, the even numbered positions (0, 2, 4, ..) are the key, the following position is the value. Would that work?

Comment: @PaulLeyten in the JSON age you should take a can of petrol and set fire to the firmware :P

Comment: @wintermute I think JSON is not arrived in Latvia :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//so. we've got the response here
var response = "!re.tag=3=.id=*1=name=1 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~!re.tag=3=.id=*2=name=3 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~!done.tag=3~";

// first we split the line into sections
var sections = Regex.Matches(response, @"!(?<set>.*?)~").Cast<Match>().Select(s=>s.Groups["set"].Value).ToArray();

// next we can parse any section into key/value pairs
var parsed = Regex.Matches(sections[0], @"(?<key>.*?)=(?<value>[^=]*)=?").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(pair => new
    {
        key = pair.Groups["key"].Value,
        value = pair.Groups["value"].Value,
    }).ToArray();
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but as you can see in response there are keys that occur more than once (id, name, etc). My guess is that they represent two records and these two are seperated by the ~ character. You should split the string among the ~ character and then use the regex on each. The author of this proprietary response format must be a misunderstood genius, to say the least.

Comment: @Bedfold there is `sections` variable wich contains individual records, so every key is unique within each secton.

Comment: @Bedford I can have misread it, but Mad Sorcerer splits the records into sections , the function next to it (the Parser) Needs to be surrounded with a foreach (var section in sections) {} and instead of parsing the sections[0] i can take the section...

Answer (score 0):

Each parameter name is starting and ending with '=' symbol. That means you need to process string looking for a first value between two '='. That ever will come after that and before next '=' symbol or end of the string is the value of that property. Property may have an empty value, so it must be handled as well.

The first part of the string is different:

```
!re.tag=3
```

You'll have to remove or process it individually.

Way to parse it would be:

```
var inString = @"=.id=*1=name=1 Hour=owner=admin=name-for-users==validity=3h=starts-at=logon=price=0=override-shared-users=off~";

        int startOfParameterName = 0;
        int endOfParameterName = 0;
        int startOfParameterValue = 0;

        bool paramerNameEndFound = false;
        bool paramerNameStartFound = false;

        var arProfiles = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for(int index = 0; index < inString.Length; index++)
        {
            if (inString[index] == '=' || index == inString.Length - 1)
            {
                if (paramerNameEndFound || index == inString.Length - 1)
                {
                    var parameterName = inString.Substring(startOfParameterName, endOfParameterName - startOfParameterName);
                    var parameterValue = startOfParameterValue == index ? string.Empty : inString.Substring(startOfParameterValue, index - startOfParameterValue);

                    arProfiles.Add(parameterName, parameterValue);

                    startOfParameterName = index + 1;
                    paramerNameEndFound = false;
                    paramerNameStartFound = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (paramerNameStartFound == false)
                    {
                        paramerNameStartFound = true;
                        startOfParameterName = index + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        paramerNameEndFound = true;
                        endOfParameterName = index;
                        startOfParameterValue = index + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Where is a room to perfection, but it works!

Comment: thank you very much for your solution! I wont take yours, but again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like each of the *values* (not the parameter names) are surrounded by a pair of "=".

This should give you what you want, more or less:

```
var input = "!re.tag=3=.id=*1=name=1 Hour=(...etc...)"; 

Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

while(input.Count() > 0){
    var keyChars = input.TakeWhile(x=> x != '=');
    var currTag = new string(keyChars.ToArray());

    var valueChars = input.Skip(currTag.Count() + 1).TakeWhile(x=> x != '=');
    var value = new string(valueChars.ToArray());

    values.Add(currTag, value);
    input = new string(input.Skip(currTag.Length + value.Lenght + 2)
                            .ToArray());
}
```

This results in the following keys and values:

```
!re.tag               | 3 
.id                   |  *1 
name                  |  1 Hour 
owner                 |  admin 
name-for-users        |   
validity              |  3h 
starts-at             |  logon 
price                 |  0 
override-shared-users |  off~
```

Comment: thanx for this solution! I wont take yours, but again thanks!